# Does new line (\n) work in xampp?

Tags: php, string, xampp

I am using xampp server to learn php and mysql, and I noticed that (\n) for a new line doesn't work?

Does anyone noticed this before in xampp?

This applies to \t,\r too.

Comment: Are you using them in single-quoted strings? They must be double-quoted to be interpreted as escape characters.

Comment: Could you show as a code example where it does not work? Only asking because there can be several causes to this.

Comment: Next, are you viewing them in the browser as HTML, which compresses whitespace and expects `<br/>` tags?

Comment: What code are you using, what do you expect (do you for instance expect to see a newline in the code, or in the browser) and what output do you get?

Comment: I am using single quotation only.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

> The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in **single quotes**
>   (the character ').
>
> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\). To
>   specify a literal backslash, double it (\\). All other instances of
>   backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the
>   **other escape sequences** you might be used to, **such as \r or \n**, **will be
>   output literally** as specified rather than having any special meaning.

So you have to use [**double quotes**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) to get `\n`, `\t` and other escaped characters (you can find a list on the linked manual page).

Your problem is not specific to XAMPP and is a general PHP thing.

Answer (score 1):

They work in xampp.

You need to use double quotes: `"\n"`